# Force Finder to use only a single window?

Tags: macos, finder

I constantly find myself closing down Finder windows. It seems that every "reveal in finder" command pops open a new finder window. This creates unwanted window clutter since I almost never need more than one finder window open at the same time. Is there any way to force Finder to reuse the same window, or to open separate tabs instead of separate windows?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured it out. Oddly, the Finder setting "Open folders in tabs instead of new windows" seems to do nothing **unless** the following setting is also in effect: `Settings > Dock > Prefer tabs when opening documents` set to `Always`.

Now commands to open folders, whether from Spotlight or "Reveal in Finder" open in new tabs instead of windows.

Comment: strange, those two have nothing to do with each other.

Answer (score 3):

Just a 2022 update on this, because macOS changed a bit. Take these steps:

1. **Finder** > **Preferences** > **General** > Check: **Open folders in tabs instead of new windows**
2. **System Preferences** > **General** > **Prefer tabs:** always

Answer (score 1):

That can be done

Go to Finder Preferences and set it like this..

Open Folders in Tabs ...

[image]

If you still want to see more Finder windows (Tabs) click on the + on the right and it will open new Tab in same window.

[image]